# haskell GADTs constructor

Tags: haskell, gadt

I have the following

```
data Expr = Condition v
          | And Expr Expr
          | Or Expr Expr
```

and I am asked to consider the follow untyped version in order to complete:

```
data Expr e where
```

I'm not sure what I'm suppose to write for the constructors. I tried the following:

```
data Expr e where
  Condition :: v -> Expr v
  And :: -- really not sure what to do with this one
  OR :: Expr b -> (Expr b -> Expr a) -> Maybe Expr a -> Expr b
```

Also, since `v` can be of any type ie `int`, `bool` etc is it possible just to call it the following (above) and declare the type of `v` later?

```
data v = IntVat int
```

any help would be much appreciated :)

**EDIT** : changed the whole post to add a little bit more information and clarity (based on my understanding of the exercise).

Basically I need help figuring out the constructors for the GADTs given the `data Expr = Condition v...etc` as reference.

Comment: The non-GADT declaration of `Expr` has no parameter (in contrast to the GADT one), is that on purpose?

Comment: @dbaupp I'd say so, since that was what was given to me for the exercise.

Comment: `V` is not a type variable (in the first definition), since it's uppercase it must refer to a specific type, right?

Comment: @Peter oh sorry, its lower case

Comment: Shouldn't your first code be 'data Expr v = Condition v | And (Expr v) (Expr v) | Or (Expr v) (Expr v)'?

Comment: @gfour as I said above, I was given the untyped `Exer`

Comment: But it is not valid Haskell, GHC/GHCi will not compile this code, so its semantics is not well-defined. Where does 'v' come from? Is it an existential (as phg proposes below), or a type variable (that should be written the proper Haskell way)?

Comment: I do not quite understand what the problem is that you are asked to solve. Could you give us a bit more information about the exercise?

Comment: @gfour i've edited the OP, hope that helps

Comment: 'data v = IntVat int': Data type names in Haskell start with a capital letter (only variables start with a lowercase letter). This means that 'int' should be 'Int' and 'v' should be 'V'. If I understand correctly, you try to leave a "hole" with 'v' in your previous definition and define here 'data v = ...' to fill it, but Haskell does not work this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were setting an assignment on GADTs using a basic expression language as the motivating example, here's the kind of answer I'd have in mind:

```
data Expr v where
    Literal :: v -> Expr v
    And     :: Expr Bool -> Expr Bool -> Expr Bool
    Or      :: Expr Bool -> Expr Bool -> Expr Bool
    -- and I'd probably add some things like this to
    -- show why the type variable is useful
    Equal   :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Bool
    If      :: Expr Bool -> Expr v -> Expr v -> Expr v
```

You can see why you might call this a "typed" expression: the instantiations of the type variables look like typing rules for a small language:

```
a : Bool         b : Bool
-------------------------
    And a b : Bool

a : Int          b : Int
------------------------
    Equal a b : Bool
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like an existential type to me. I must admit, I've never really used them, I only tried to understand them; anyway, maybe it's meant like this:

```
data Expr = forall v. Condition v
          | And Expr Expr
          | Or Expr Expr
```

Then you had a GADT like this (they generalize existentials, see [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html)):

```
data Expr where
    Condition :: v -> Expr
    And :: Expr -> Expr -> Expr
    Or :: Expr -> Expr -> Expr
```

Although, that wouldn't (as far as I understood the concept) make much sense, since you can't use `v` for anything.

On the other hand, *this* would (I hope) make more sense (since there's a "condition"):

```
class Testable v where
    test :: v -> Bool

data Expr where
    Condition :: Testable v => v -> Expr
    And :: Expr -> Expr -> Expr
    Or :: Expr -> Expr -> Expr
```

then you could do, e.g.

```
eval :: Expr -> Bool
eval (Condition v) = test v
eval (And e1 e2) = (eval e1) && (eval e2)
eval (Or e1 e2) = (eval e1) || (eval e2)
```

which would work for different kinds of "conditions".

I didn't test this code, though, and, as I've said, I'm not really a professional about existentials. I hope my code is correct, but please tell me anyone, if you know better (or I'm totally wrong...)

Comment: `data Expr` is an untyped version of the `Expr`

Comment: `Expr` as existential (with the forall) is "untyped", too, in the sense that it has kind `*`. However, it can store different types, which are later accessible by pattern matching the constructor. Also, I agree with gfour, that leaving those `v`s probably was a mistake. Adding them would lead to a normal, tree-like recursive type.